# Is there a way to infer the keys of a mapped type when using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, mapped-types

I have a data structure that represents my business operations:

```
const operations = {
    list: {
        request: "a",
        response: "b",
    },
    get: {
        request: "a",
        response: "b",
    },
} as const;
```

I want to create a function that  will accept callbacks based on the `operations` above:

```
type Ops = typeof operations;

type Callbacks = {
    [Property in keyof Ops]: (
        param: Ops[Property]["request"]
    ) => Ops[Property]["response"];
};
```

Now if I want to define my callbacks the compiler will complain if I miss any of them:

```
const callbacks: Callbacks = {

};
// ^^^--- Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Callbacks': list, get
```

Now my problem is that I want to create another type so that I can type check the `operations` object's structure:

```
interface OperationDescriptor<A, B> {
    request: A;
    response: B;
}

type Operations = {
    [key: string]: OperationDescriptor<any, any>;
};

const operations: Operations = {
    list: {
        request: "a",
        response: "b",
    },
    get: {
        request: "a",
        response: "b",
    },
} as const; // okay

const badOperations: Operations = {
    list: {
        request: "a",
        response: "b",
    },
    get: { // error, missing response prop
        request: "a",        
    },
} as const;
```

but when I do this the compiler will no longer complain because `Operations` doesn't know about my keys in `operations`. Is there a way to have my cake and eat it too, eg:

- Define a type that I can use to typecheck the structure of `operations` and
- to have a `Callbacks` type that will typecheck my callback functions based on the structure of `operations`?

Comment: Could you please [edit] this to be a [mre] we can easily copy and paste into our own IDEs and get to work on it? Third-party or private types and values make it harder to get started.  My *guess* is going to be that you want [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) but I can't check that without a [mre].

Comment: • Can you check out your code in a standalone IDE and make sure it's a [mre]? I don't know what `string` as a runtime value is supposed to be. • "the compiler will no longer complain" can you show this?  Ideally the example lets us copy and paste into our own IDEs and see the issue clearly. • And again maybe `satisfies` is what you want, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mxEv1W), but I'm trying to see something super obvious that demonstrates it.

Comment: I'm not sure what's not working in the example but `satisfies` solves my problem.

Comment: If you put that into an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I've made the edit I think is needed to make it a [mre]. Let me know if that is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to check that a value is assignable to a type without *widening* it to that type. It's made exactly for the situation where a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) would forget information you care about:

```
const operations = {
    list: {
        request: "a",
        response: "b",
    },
    get: {
        request: "a",
        response: "b",
    },
} as const satisfies Operations;
```

If the above compiles then you know that you're okay. Otherwise you get the errors you expect:

```
const badOperations = {
    list: {
        request: "a",
        response: "b",
    },
    get: { // error!
    //~ <-- Property 'response' is missing
        request: "a",
    },
} as const satisfies Operations;
```

And the type `typeof operations` is still exactly as detailed as you need it to be:

```
type Ops = typeof operations;
/* type Ops = {
    readonly list: {
        readonly request: "a";
        readonly response: "b";
    };
    readonly get: {
        readonly request: "a";
        readonly response: "b";
    };
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAdpzMA9iAEQgGcEph0xcoAeAQQBpkAhAPmQG8AoZX5KCAEcAriTAAuZHQDcPPgOLp8xCJOayAvly5gAnpjSYo2PCGLIAvJzm8A2gGsIuycTDkQAcwC6kjFhz4RKTklNQ0cCC6TBG6rJqyXAjKYMi4RibKltZ8yAA2wK6S3Dk5AiJikgBEcJUMNiUKSmaqyJUARrX1GnU5HhAS2SW8ZaKFrTU9Q-wkTSpVHZO83VwayHDmSWYpxCbEMMAkhv6mxAmbrshtcAAmfsYBZlnFfPljz0MjFeOdU9OKyi12j8+Mtev0isgAPSQ5DQKDUACE9Ry0IAfsgaABaTHIAAK8KMemQAHJGgDicgCsgALYFYigDzI+RCUYDarApZ1VbrZDnba7faHO4ZMwJHT6FAYcxWPSYXAwVLpB6nLiQgBUyFlkvQ0sGwwgN3wuV0eQKA3eDQN1yNJs+Y3Zsl+AkNIGNf1mgI6jpB3v1LrdfXNTL91tdtpZXwdwem-vD-2a80qvuQGk0yDVkO04oMAGE4LlclcEPZdRbbPi0tAiaBkI5dPLDMQfMgABTR9BwYzU3w68sEqu6Ly2Sp2sCVLz1ACUlnYUr7lageiHI5mAPH8W0QA)